# jQuery UI Slider with jQuery Tools Scrollable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-tools

Anyone ever seen an example (or tutorial perferably) of using the [jQuery UI slider element](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) to control a [jQuery Tools Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html)? I'm looking to build a timeline-type page and want to have a horizontal scrollable that has the possibility of having a vertical scrollable within it. Looking to control it via a slider like the one built into jQUery UI.

I'd rather not re-invent the wheel when I'm pretty sure something already exists out there.

Comment: Still haven't found a suitable solution for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easly link the `change` event of the slider to the `seekTo` function of the Scrollable element, for example:

```
$( ".slider" ).slider({
     change: function(event, ui) {
           myScrollable.seekTo( $( ".slider" ).slider( "value" ) , 0 );
     }
});
```

And you also want to update the slider once the scrollable has moved (if there's another way to move around).

```
var myScrollable = $( ".scrollable" ). scrollable({
     onSeek:function(){
           $( ".slider" ).slider( "value" , myScrollable.getIndex() );
     }
})
```